# Deleted libxml2.dylib

Tags: xcode, libxml2

I accidentally  deleted the libxml2.dylib file from my system (Xcode can't find it by "Choose frameworks ..."). How can I get it back?
I did the following:
- inserted the libxml2.dylib via "build phases" Tab
- removed it from the build phase
- removed it from the project
- choosed "move to trash"
- cleared the trash

greetings
Leon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue, deleted by mistake a *.dylib library and had problems compiling my project...

The way to solve this is to copy the missing *.dylib files from the user's library back to the SDK destination.

In my case the missing file was "libz.1.2.5.dylib", so I did:

```
cp /usr/lib/libz.1.2.5.dylib /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/usr/lib/
```

Reopen Xcode and it is solved... :)